# The ckeditor appears as a disabled component

Tags: angular, ckeditor, text-editor, disable

I created a ckeditor  by  [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) and implement it in Angular 16.[text](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/angular.html#integrating-a-build-from-the-online-builder)
When I upload the component it comes up as disabled.
I tried to manually change the feature but no change
Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks

I'm tried to change it by the method:
editor.enableReadOnlyMode( 'feature-id' );

and the property disabled = false in the element.